# Android writing performance

Tags: android, performance

If I need to save some data in files.
I have two options:

1. Save in same File everything, but it complicate code a lot.
2. Save in 20-25 small Files, it is much easier than 1 option

What is difference between performances of this two option?

I would like to use second option, but I'm not sure does it affect performance of my app.

I need to load all these files on start of application, and sometimes to update some of them.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `SharedPreferences`. If you need to save binary data, use separate files, ZIP files, or encode the binary data into **base64** and save it then into a shared preference.

Comment: Share performance is not adequate option for saving these data.

Comment: no matter what, loading data from 20ish files will take time. You can do this, but will need to implement some loading/splash screen until your loading/updating is done.

Comment: Can SharedPreferances support lot of data well?

Comment: I need to save about 200 characters in every file or 20*200 characters in one big file

Comment: @FilipV Consider this, 20*200=4000 characters is only 4KB-16KB. It is highly unlikely that this will be a real performance problem either way, so pick whichever one is more convenient for you. If UI lag is your concern, wrap the accesses in an `AsyncTask`.

Comment: I know but I don't know how much time does it take to switch to another file